# Tensor product of enriched functors

Tags: category-theory

I am sure this must have been defined somewhere, but I can not find any reference. Say $F$ and $G$ are $V$-enriched functors, where $V$ is a symmetric monoidal category. How is $F\otimes_V G$ defined?

Comment: Could you cite the reference where you've seen this tensor product between functors?

Comment: The tensor of enriched categories is defined in Kelly's book as a $2$-functor. The tensor of $V$-functors is the action of this functor on morphisms.

Comment: The weighted colimit $F \ast G$ for $V$-functors $F : A^{op} \to V$ and $G : A \to B$ is sometimes called the tensor product of functors. This generalises the tensor product of modules, seen as Ab-enriched functors to Ab.

Answer (score 2):

In the unenriched setup, the tensor product of two functors over some category is defined as a coend. Given a category $\mathcal{C}$, a monoidal category $(\mathcal{V}, \otimes)$, the tensor product of $F : \mathcal{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathcal{V}$ and $G : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{V}$ is defined to be the object
$F \otimes_{\mathcal{C}} G := \int^{c \in \mathcal{C}} F(c) \otimes G(c)$. In more words, $F \otimes_{\mathcal{C}} G$ is an object of $\mathcal{V}$ together with a collection of arrows $(F(c) \otimes G(c) \xrightarrow{\alpha_c} F \otimes_{\mathcal{C}} G : c \in \mathcal{C})$ such that for every arrow $f : c \rightarrow c'$ in $\mathcal{C}$,
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(c') \otimes G(c) @>{F(f^{op}) \otimes 1_{Gc}}>> F(c) \otimes G(c)\\
@V{1_{Fc'} \otimes G(f)}VV @V{\alpha_c}VV \\
F(c') \otimes G(c') @>{\alpha_{c'}}>> F \otimes_{\mathcal{C}} G
\end{CD}$$commutes and such that the pair $(F \otimes_{\mathcal{C}} G, \alpha)$ is universal with respect to this property.
This in particular generalizes the tensor product of a right module and a left module.

In the enriched setup, the coend is just replaced by the corresponding enriched coend, assuming that $\mathcal{V}$ is closed symmetric monoidal.

---

There is another completely different meaning of tensor products of two $\mathcal{V}$-enriched functors $F : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and $G : \mathcal{C}' \rightarrow \mathcal{D}'$. Given a symmetric monoidal $\mathcal{V},\text{ }\otimes : \mathcal{V}-\textbf{CAT} \times \mathcal{V}-\textbf{CAT} \rightarrow \mathcal{V}-\textbf{CAT}$ is a 2-functor whose action on the 1-cells ($\mathcal{V}$-functors) is given by :

$F \otimes G : \mathcal{C} \otimes \mathcal{C}' \rightarrow \mathcal{D} \otimes \mathcal{D}'$
: $(c, c') \mapsto (F(c), G(c'))$; $(F \otimes G)_{(c_1,c_1'),(c_2,c_2')} = F_{(c_1,c_2)} \otimes G_{(c_1',c_2')} : \mathcal{C}(c_1,c_2) \otimes \mathcal{C}'(c_1',c_2') \rightarrow \mathcal{D}(F(c_1),F(c_2)) \otimes \mathcal{D}'(G(c_1'), G(c_2'))$.